# Silverlight 4, WCF RIA Services generated incomplete code

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

- I started with the Silverlight Business Application Template

  - I will call this MyApp and MyApp.Web
- I added a new SL application project.
- and added a ria link to the existing web project.

  - I will call this Loader

This new SL app is the entry point of my solution, and basically loads the mainpage from the other xap file. Checks for updates, etc.

- I removed the App.xaml and App.xs files from MyApp
- Because Loader is now the Application

  - I copied the relevant code from MyApp - App.cs to Loader - App.cs
  - I added the relevant code from MyApp - App.xaml to Loader - App.xaml
  - Mostly this is the WebContext stuff.

The problem is that the RIA Services *generated* code for **Loader** is not the same code as the code for **MyApp**

The generated code for MyApp contains the following namespaces:

- MyApp
- MyApp.Web
- MyApp.Web.Models
- MyApp.Web.Services

The generated code for Loader contains the namespace:

- Loader

The following line of code in Loader - App.cs throws **InvalidOperationException**.

```
WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser(this.Application_UserLoaded, null);
```

The error msg for the exception is:

> The DomainContextType is null or invalid and there are no contexts generated from `AuthenticationBase<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this same problem (with a similar setup) today. After looking around a little bit, I found [this post on the silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/112195.aspx) which has the answer (look in the bottom for the solution, since there were some API changes in RIA Services).

Long story short, the issue is that your WebContext can't *find* the DomainContext (in this case an `AuthenticationContext`) that handles `LoadUser` in your case. to solve this problem you'll need to add the following to your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <dmnsvc:WebContext>
        <dmnsvc:WebContext.Authentication>
            <appsvc:FormsAuthentication>
                <appsvc:FormsAuthentication.DomainContext>
                    <!--Your AuthenticationContext here-->
                </appsvc:FormsAuthentication.DomainContext>
            </appsvc:FormsAuthentication>
        </dmnsvc:WebContext.Authentication>
    </dmnsvc:WebContext>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Hope this helps :)